# Loop through IEnumerable in @Html.DropDownListFor (MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, collections

I have a collection of models that I am passing to my view and I want to display each model.property in the dropdownlist. The problem is there is a bug in my code where it shows two duplicate items.

```
@model IEnumerable<UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model>

@Html.Label("BRAD Module:")&nbsp
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().module_name, Model.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.module_name, Value = x.module_name }), new { id = "ddlSelectedBrad", onchange = "chkSelection()" })
```

I am currently using FirstOrDefault() to access the module name for each model in my collection of models. But by doing this I have a duplicate value.

See screenshots below:

[image]

MARKET:LEISURE is showing twice

[image]

Intelligence is showing twice. If I change this dropdown value and return to this screen it will show two duplicate values.
**Summary**

Does anyone know a better way of writing the LINQ query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Model.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.module_name, Value = x.module_name })
```

Try

```
Model.GroupBy(x => x.module_name).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.First().module_name, Value = x.First().module_name })
```

This should filter the duplicate records.